# Clustering algorithms based on lists of most similar items?

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining, clustering, dataset

I'm a beginner to machine learning. I have a large dataset of items, each with a limited set of most similar items in the dataset, which I would like to create clusters of, preferably each having the same size, although this isn't necessary. Could someone point me in the right direction? Thanks.

Comment: What items, what domain? You need to give a minimal example of what your data looks like, otherwise it is hard to give suggestions.

Comment: @MajidMortazavi I've already said it in the post. It's a list of IDs, each having a list of the 20 most similar IDs in the dataset. That's all there is.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for K-means clustering to cluster the data based on the pattern.

Answer (score 0):

All clustering algorithms, by default cluster the **most similar items**.

If you are searching for a specific similarity (e.g. similar size) you need to select an **appropriate distance metric** (e.g. one that compares sizes).

Comment: I'm aware. My point is that the only information I have for each item in the dataset is a list of the 20 most similar items from the rest of the set.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is modelling your problem as a graph where the nodes would be the items and the edges would be the relationships from your most similar list. You could even add a weight if your most-similar-item list ranks the items in order of similarity. Afterwards you could try to apply a graph clustering technique.

Answer (score 0):

Look at graph clustering algorithms.

You have an edge from each item to it's most similar items.

You can then use e.g. spectral clustering.